# CCMoveTo of Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have two CCSprite on the scene

CCSprite *spriteA;
CCSprite *spriteB;

spriteB's position is fixed,and spriteA's position is not.I touch the spriteA,and it only can be moved by the way a straight line, only four direction "up/down/left/right"，not slash,and also it can be moved until the spriteB stop it. such as I(spriteA) can keep running until the wall(spriteB) front of me stopping me.

i use the following code

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
return YES;}
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
[spriteA stopAllActions];
[spriteA runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:convertedLocation]];
```

}

it can be moved,but not only four direction, and how can i use spriteB stop spriteA,if spriteB is at the front of spriteA?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty big, so I'm gonna try and reply on a high-level.

First off, you should look into gesture recognizers. For cocos2D, you have to use install this special class: [CCGestureRecognizer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8929). This class is in essence a wrapper for the standard UIGestureRecognizer classes on iOS.

The gesture recognizer you want to use is [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This gesture recognizer tells you when a swipe is detected in a certain direction. The four directions available are the ones you are looking for. The four directions are defined as an enum : UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection. When you register the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, you will be notified when the user swipes in any of these directions.

For the second part of your question, you need collision detection. Cocos2D has a built in physics engine that should help you with this, given that that your CCSprite shapes are roughly convex. You can find a [great tutorial here on how to do collision detection in box2d here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone).

I hope this helps you on your way.